# Extended events not capturing Entity Framework queries (read/updates)

Tags: entity-framework, extended-events

I had added the Extended event to track sql calls which is slowing down my system leading to Timeout exceptions and other

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [longrunning_statements] ON SERVER 
      ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(
WHERE ([duration]>(2000000) AND [database_id]=(9)))
      ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'c:\capture\xe_longrunning_statement.xel',metadatafile=N'c:\capture\xe_longrunning_statement.xem')
       WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
 GO
```

But i noticed it does not register sql server updates/read queries/procedures calls from Entity Framework but only logged my sql queries run using SSMS.

Any ideas are appreciated

UPDATE:

I use EF6.1 which used i think batches to save data.

Comment: Try to remove the filters one by one, to see which one is causing the exclusion of these events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to capture `sqlserver.sql_statement_completed` I would capture `sqlserver.sql_batch_completed` and `sqlserver.rpc_completed` for application/API issued queries/stored procedures.

If that does not work then removing the filters(or at least the `duration` filter (as Andrey is suggesting in the comments) would probably give us more insight on why the queries are not being captured.